# How to delay background to show after the popup appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I want the popup to show once the page is load. I have made the popup everything working fine I but there is one issue page shows just for a split second before the popup. I want the popup to load first without showing the page.

This is the link of the page http://test2429d.vinnugrunnur.is/home popup has video which runs for 7 second and disappear.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: I have created it using Elementor Page builder widget. I just want the background not to show before the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your [sample site](http://test2429d.vinnugrunnur.is/home/), you will have to hide the content and unhide it when you hide the popup.

The reason being your popup is dynamically being added using Javascript. So the popup won't get shown until the page is completely loaded.

There are several ways to do this. If this popup is only limited to this page, you can perhaps use the body class as a reference to hide your `.jupiterx-site`.

```
body.elementor-page-10 .jupiterx-site {
    display: none;
}
```

And your Javascript should unhide it after 7 seconds

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      // setTimeout() function will be fired after page is loaded
      // it will wait for 5 sec. and then will fire
      // $("#successMessage").hide() function
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.eael-lightbox-popup-window').fadeOut('slow');
    jQuery('.jupiterx-site').show();
  }, 7000); 
});
```

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      // setTimeout() function will be fired after page is loaded
      // it will wait for 5 sec. and then will fire
      // $("#successMessage").hide() function
  setTimeout(function() {
 jQuery('.eael-lightbox-popup-window').fadeOut(2000);
}, 7000); 
});

this is my code it still show background for a split second before loading the popup

Comment: How do you show `.eael-lightbox-popup-window`? I need the HTML too.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have made it using wordpress elementor page builder here is the link of the website https://aldeilis.is/test-2/ if that helps

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef I've already seen it from your question so no, that doesn't help. All I see is a blank screen. Even the HTML only contained 2 empty divs.

Comment: I am sorry this is the link http://test2429d.vinnugrunnur.is/home the other link is not open for public I have made this page available for you to see.

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef Thanks. I've updated my answer using the information you've provided.